# Blurry Panoramic Rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

[image]I've searched on google a few times now and none of the proposed fixes work for me as you might find with the below images:

In order from top to bottom: The first is to show what the object actually looks like as well as the dimensions I've set, like aspect ratio and resolution etc. The second picture is to show denoising is apparently off. The third picture is to show what I get...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what are your camera settings?

Comment: Added to the OP at the top, it's another picture...

Comment: hmh, your settings seem right. Only thing i could imagine now is that you're zoomed in, in the renderview and that your resolution for this kind of projection rendering is too low. Try it with 7680px x 4320px. Or move your object closer to the camera.

Comment: Hmm ok... Can people still zoom out to get a good idea of the whole object if I move the camera closer?

Comment: Looks like moving the camera forward helped-- problem is now it's stunted-- the render makes the sword look like a dagger if that makes sense. Do I need to use some sort of 3rd party software to fix it up or?

Comment: Answer was the comment that @Chris mentioned, specifically moving the camera.

Comment: yeah, that transformation happens in a panoramic shot :) You can fix it in Photoshop, but then the question arises, why not render it as a regular perspective image?